# Replacing background image and element text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background-image, custom-data-attribute

I am building a script to inject a custom text and image to an HTML page with a rather complicated structure:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="result">
      <div class="div_result">
        <div class="display">
          <div class="record-icon pubtype">
            <span class="pubtype-icon"></span>
            <p class="text">icon text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="links">
            <span class="custom-link"><a class="icon-image-link" href="image.jpg" onclick="string">String<a/></span>
            <span class="custom-link"><a class="icon-image-link" href="image.jpg" onclick="string">String<a/></span>
            <span class="custom-link"><a class="icon-image-link" href="image.jpg" onclick="string">String<a/></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I have written a JavaScript that is meant to search for a specific substring in the a elements, and if that exists, to change the background image of the .icon span and the text of the .text p element, based on input from the user:

```
try {
  var backgroundcontainer= setInterval("addMyScript()", 100);

  function addMyScript() {
    if (!window.jQuery){return;}
    clearInterval(backgroundcontainer); //clean interval

    jQuery(function() {
      var pubtypes = $('#custompubtypeicon').data('pubtypes');
      var icons = $('#custompubtypeicon').data('icons');
      pubtypes.forEach(Function() {
        var elementclass = document.getElementsByClassName("icon-image-link");
        var index = $(pubtypes).indexOf($(this));
        elementclass.forEach(replace() {
          if ($(this).attr('onclick').indexOf('pbt=')+pubtypes[index] > -1) {
            $(this).closest('.pubtype-icon').style.backgroundImage = icons[index];
            $(this).closest("div.record-icon p").text(pubtypes[index]);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.info(err);
}
```

I am getting an error message `missing ) after argument list` which is preventing me from testing the rest of the code. I ran a validation on http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html and the problem is reported for line 12 as:

> "Unexpected identifier" (line 12 is var elementclass = document.getElementsByClassName("icon-image-link");)

I imagine there are many more issues to solve until the code works properly, but this blocks me from continuing.
I checked several solutions online (including here), but they all deal with simple missing brackets, and line 12 does not seem to have any missing elements.

Comment: It could be because you are targeting multiple elements, i.e. every instance of the class `icon-image-link`, which you have multiple of, without putting the value into an array variable. Not sure that is the only error though, but an easy way to see if that's actually the issue would be to try a different approach, or make you code work without that line specifically. If it does, then you know that it was in fact that line that caused the issue.

Comment: @Martin that line DOES cause an issue, you are right.
I removed it and changed line 14 to: $(".icon-image-link").each(function() {
Now I get no error messages in the page, but the page does not change at all. I'll need to check why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these mistakes

- `pubtypes.forEach(Function() {` line should be `pubtypes.forEach(function() {` - function without capital `F`
- `elementclass.forEach(replace() {` again it should be `function` not `replace` - `elementclass.forEach(function () {`
- `<a>...<a/>` should be `<a>...</a>`

```js
try {
  var backgroundcontainer= setInterval("addMyScript()", 100);

  function addMyScript() {
  if (!window.jQuery){return;}
    clearInterval(backgroundcontainer); //clean interval

    jQuery(function() {
      var pubtypes = $('#custompubtypeicon').data('pubtypes');
      var icons = $('#custompubtypeicon').data('icons');
      pubtypes.forEach(function(){
        var elementclass = document.getElementsByClassName("icon-image-link");
        var index = $(pubtypes).indexOf($(this));

        elementclass.forEach(function () {
          if ($(this).attr('onclick').indexOf('pbt=')+pubtypes[index] > -1) {
            $(this).closest('.pubtype-icon').style.backgroundImage = icons[index];
            $(this).closest("div.record-icon p").text(pubtypes[index]);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.info(err);
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="result">
    <div class="div_result">
      <div class="display">
        <div class="record-icon pubtype">
          <span class="pubtype-icon"></span>
          <p class="text">icon text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
          <span class="custom-link"><a class="icon-image-link" href="image.jpg" onclick="string">String</a></span>
          <span class="custom-link"><a class="icon-image-link" href="image.jpg" onclick="string">String</a></span>
          <span class="custom-link"><a class="icon-image-link" href="image.jpg" onclick="string">String</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That indeed solved the issue in the original message!
Along with Martin's comment, this solved all errors.

Thank you very much!